# Intellij editor freezing with a stackoverflow

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, groovy, crash

I am using Intellij on ubuntu:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.4892.20, built on October 16, 2018
Subscription is active until November 3, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b19 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
```

Recently I began running into the following error appearing after a couple of seconds after startup of IntelliJ:
The editor freezes. Killing the process and starting again allows to get an error message about the last crash:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.isDependencyOutOfDate(CachedValueBase.java:138)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.isDependencyOutOfDate(PsiCachedValue.java:74)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.isUpToDate(CachedValueBase.java:128)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.isUpToDate(PsiCachedValue.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getUpToDateOrNull(CachedValueBase.java:107)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:214)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.DataBindingProjectComponent.getDataBindingEnabledFacets(DataBindingProjectComponent.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.DataBindingProjectComponent.hasAnyDataBindingEnabledFacet(DataBindingProjectComponent.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.BrClassFinder.isEnabled(BrClassFinder.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.BrClassFinder.findClass(BrClassFinder.java:54)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.doFindClass(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.findClass(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiManager.createTypeByFQClassName(GroovyPsiManager.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapTypeFromNamedArgs.getAllKeyTypes(GrMapTypeFromNamedArgs.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.VolatileNotNullLazyValue.getValue(VolatileNotNullLazyValue.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType.getParameters(GrMapType.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getCanonicalText(GrLiteralClassType.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getQualifiedName(TypesUtil.java:838)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBound(TypesUtil.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBoundNullable(TypesUtil.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getLeastUpperBound(GrLiteralClassType.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.VolatileNotNullLazyValue.getValue(VolatileNotNullLazyValue.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType.getParameters(GrMapType.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getCanonicalText(GrLiteralClassType.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getQualifiedName(TypesUtil.java:838)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBound(TypesUtil.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBoundNullable(TypesUtil.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getLeastUpperBound(GrLiteralClassType.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.VolatileNotNullLazyValue.getValue(VolatileNotNullLazyValue.java:34)
```

The stack trace continues, repeating like that for hundreds of times. Any clues how to fix this?

Edit: As recommended in a comment I disabled the Android-Plugin. The error still occurs in a similar fashion. Just the first couple of lines did change:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getFromCache(DefaultPicoContainer.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:30)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ProjectFileIndex.getInstance(ProjectFileIndex.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ProjectFileIndex$SERVICE.getInstance(ProjectFileIndex.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.getFileIndex(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaSourceFilterScope.<init>(JavaSourceFilterScope.java:49)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaSourceFilterScope.<init>(JavaSourceFilterScope.java:38)
    at com.intellij.lang.aspectj.search.AjSourceFilterScope.<init>(AjSourceFilterScope.java:22)
    at com.intellij.lang.aspectj.index.stub.AjShortClassNameIndex.get(AjShortClassNameIndex.java:29)
    at com.intellij.lang.aspectj.search.AjClassFinder.findClass(AjClassFinder.java:23)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.doFindClass(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.findClass(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.resolve(GrLiteralClassType.java:149)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiPrimitiveType.getUnboxedType(PsiPrimitiveType.java:180)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiPrimitiveType.getOptionallyUnboxedType(PsiPrimitiveType.java:191)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getNumericLUB(TypesUtil.java:484)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBound(TypesUtil.java:412)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBoundNullable(TypesUtil.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getLeastUpperBound(GrLiteralClassType.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.VolatileNotNullLazyValue.getValue(VolatileNotNullLazyValue.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType.getParameters(GrMapType.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getCanonicalText(GrLiteralClassType.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getQualifiedName(TypesUtil.java:838)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBound(TypesUtil.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBoundNullable(TypesUtil.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getLeastUpperBound(GrLiteralClassType.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.VolatileNotNullLazyValue.getValue(VolatileNotNullLazyValue.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType.getParameters(GrMapType.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getCanonicalText(GrLiteralClassType.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getQualifiedName(TypesUtil.java:838)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBound(TypesUtil.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.TypesUtil.getLeastUpperBoundNullable(TypesUtil.java:395)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrLiteralClassType.getLeastUpperBound(GrLiteralClassType.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GrMapType$1.compute(GrMapType.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.VolatileNotNullLazyValue.getValue(VolatileNotNullLazyValue.java:34)
```

Comment: Try restarting your computer?

Comment: I tried restarting my computer. I also reinstalled IntelliJ.

Comment: If you aren't working on any Android projects, disable the Android plugin - this will fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it did also not help to disable the Android plugin. The problem still occurs even after a restart. The repeating part of the stack trace still appears. Just the first couple of lines changed. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @FalkTandetzky please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the logs folder zipped (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: I did file a bug at
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201266
(not visible to the public)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the IntelliJ support, this issue was resolved. I did deactivate and later reactivate the groovy-Plugin. After that the problem no longer appeared.